# Unable to find where PHP installed after installing Xampp

Tags: php, installation, xampp

I used the [following link](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#641) to download the latest Xampp in order to install php on a windows. I clicked on "Installer" and installed it on my computer. Now I can't seem to find php on my machine. What should I do next?

Comment: Have you tried to load up xampp and execute a php file within the web root directory?

Comment: I wrote `php -v` in the command line, and it doesn't recognize it

Comment: @LucyWeatherford `php -v` will only be recognized if the xampp bin directory for php is defined in your environment PATH variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you must start the apache server and mysql through xampp control panel. and then directly try with browser like http://localhost/

Also you need to save the php files in C:/program files/xampp/htdocs/your folder name / (If you installed xampp in C drive )

Wherever you installed that exe create a xampp folder automatically. XAMPP folder contains all the database, server configuration files and php files

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.. I opened up xampp, now what to do?

Comment: Okay I am running it, how do I use the command line? the xampp_start.php is not letting me write anything there, the cmd of the computer is not recognizing php; but the localhost is clearly running xampp

Comment: If you opened up the Xampp control panel there is options to start mysql, apache, Please start all these.

Comment: also, it seems that the php files were saved under `c:/xampp/htdocs', should I change this to what you suggested?

Comment: They are both running; there are 3 problems possibly: 2 by xampp:
`21:37:02  [apache]     "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" seems to be running on port XX?
21:37:02  [apache]  "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" seems to be running on port XXX?
21:37:02  [mysql]  Possible problem detected: Port XXXX in use by "mysqld.exe"!`
And the third, the command line is still not recognizing `php -v` when I ask

Comment: @LucyWeatherford The standard ports for apache are `80` and `443` is used for ssl, mysql generally runs under `3306`.  If you are receiving that as a startup notification there should be no concern, if it is a startup failure message, you likely already have an instance of xampp running.  And I mentioned the `php -v` issue in a comment to the question already.  There should be no concern as to whether or not `php` is in your path if you are not going to be scripting with it and only serving php files with apache.

Comment: @SteveBuzonas thanks! I was able to get it to work yesterday after adding to the path (I do intend to script on the command line as well).
however now the apache won't turn on? `make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available, shutting down 
unable to open logs` and the apache won't turn on :(

Comment: @LucyWeatherford Is anything else running on port 80?  You can do `netstat -ano` from a command line to show the open ports and the PID associated with them.  I know in *nix you need to have administrative access to run on a port below 1024.  This may also be an issue if you are not running apache with administrative privileges.