# apache in xampp won't turn on - after it worked before

Tags: windows, apache, installation, xampp

I recently installed Xampp on my windows machine. It worked when I just did it, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124044/unable-to-find-where-php-installed-after-installing-xampp/9124096#comment11475134_9124096). However, now the apache won't turn on. I realize that I did not close it correctly (did not use xampp_stop), so maybe that could be the cause.

The error I am getting is:

```
    make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 
    no listening sockets available, shutting down 
    unable to open logs
```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Just ran into the same issue. Skype was to blame. After an auto update the options were set *again* to use the port 80. Had to disable that option once more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up solving it. 
Go to the Xampp control panel. Check the "Service" check box.
Clicked on "SCM" button. (Or "Service" button, there on the "SCM" button). 
Then I clicked on the "Apache" in the list of services. Turned it on. 

 Now it is labelled as "Running" in the control panel, and "localhost" works.

Comment: Odd that it won't work as a process! If you figure out why, please let me know I'm curious. We ran into an install of Windows that had a similar problem and our solution ended up being reinstalling windows, but for reasons other than the failure of Xampp's apache running.

Comment: no, I don't know why, but there seems to be "beta version 3" control panel of xampp we ended up using, the regular control panel wouldn't open after all this.

Answer (score 12):

Just ran into this very well do documented blog with respect to Apache not working.. I think its really good to reference if you have apache startup issues.

[apache friends](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=162462)

here are the steps that i note from the link:

- Check that xampp folder is not in a folder containing spaces or brackets  ie (Program Files (x86)
- Make sure that you have run \xampp\setup_xampp.bat   (probably as administrator)
- in CMD run -netstat -a   (or look in Xampp control beta 3 - and press the netstat button... ) , make sure that nothing is running on port 80 ( on win 7 a lot of the time its actually skype that uses port 80) ( quit skype and try again, if so, in skype --> options ->> advanced  --> make sure the "use port 80 as alternative checkbox is unchecked"
- If "system"  is using port 80, then its windows that is using it ( i have read that that is some IIS service) - if you enable xampp as a service and re-boot then xampp grabs port 80 before system...
- If you dont want to run as a service then open xampp\apache\conf\http.conf and change the port that apache will run on  (search for string "Listen 80" and "ServerName localhost:80" and change 80 to something else eg: "180")
- Make sure you are running Xampp control.exe as administrator
- Stop your firewall temporarily to see if its being stopped (then try startup apache again) if so, create an exception in windows firewall
- Check that your anti-virus is not stopping it.
- If you are running windows 7 64 bit ultimate (sp1) (like i am) - then you may still have a problem (like i am)
- last try is to delete xampp folder, and download a previous version of xampp, then try again.

If you have any other steps that you think may also cause a problem, please comment.

Comment: It was Skype (on another user, so I initially did not notice it was running). Thanks @Hightower !

Comment: After moving xampp, running `\xampp\setup_xampp.bat` alone isn't the solution. I was stuck in similar situation until I figured out the I needed to change the `DocumentRoot` to point to my new path in all virtual host definitions in `xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`. I hope it helps somebody

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue a couple months ago. You have to set Apache as an automatic windows service by checking the Svc checkbox in the XAMPP Control Panel.  Once you have set it as a service, you will need to restart windows before you can start apache.  Once you have restarted windows, you should be able to stop and start Apache through the XAMPP Control Panel.

From [a blog post about it](http://myphpjourney.blogspot.com/2011/12/apache-wont-run-after-installing-xampp.html):

> The reason you have to do this is because Windows 7 has a service called http.sys which starts automatically and uses port 80. Running Apache as an automatic service causes apache to start before the http.sys service. This allows apache to get port 80 before http.sys starts.

Answer (score 4):

One: If it is running as a service, check your services in windows and make sure it is stopped.

Two: If it is not a service, it will just be a process; go into the task manager and find httpd / apache and terminate the process.

Three: Make sure you are running xampp_start / xampp_control as administrator, on some systems this is important.

I would recommend always using xampp_control as it gives a quick window into whether Apache is supposedly running or not even if some unusual events recently occurred.

Try

```
netstat -aon | more
```

If this doesn't work, to see if anything else is listening on that port, and terminate that process.

You may also wish to edit Apache's httpd.conf (probably in xamppdir/apache/conf) to listen to another port and see if it will launch.

Comment: I am trying the control panel, but it won't let me start Apache. It says "busy" every time I click on "start" the Apache (first it says `Apache started [port 80]`, then immediately disconnects and says `busy`). How do I know if it is a service or a process? I think it is a process, not service, but I can't seem to find it in my task manager...

Comment: ps - how do I check if I'm running as administrator or not?

Comment: In the control panel there should be a check that says 'svc' or 'service'; if it's not checked, it's running as a process. To run as administrator, right-click on the executable and you should see a 'run as administrator' option, provided you have those access rights. You'll need to close the current instance of the panel first.

Comment: Also, it's good to make sure that in the interim you didn't start running some other process that listens on Port 80. One way to that is to go to your browser and type 'localhost'.

Comment: no, nothing is running, I checked the browser. I tried both as service or process, and both won't work, as svc the problem is similar - it says `Apache server started` and then disconnects. I just tried to `run as administrator` and had the same problem :( I closed everything related first...

Comment: What version of windows are you running?

Comment: I'm using windows 7 Home Premium, 64

Comment: I tried your new suggestion, there are a bunch of `listening` on 0.0.0.0, but none in 0.0.0.0:80

Comment: should I terminate them? and how?

Comment: I don't think they are the problem, try to change the port apache is listening on. http://www.boolcast.com/lamp/apache/make-apache-listen-on-a-different-port

Comment: I ended up succeeding, through the control panel, writing it up now... thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1. change the httpd.cong file in those lines:

   `Listen 8080`

   `ServerName localhost:8080 ( port as example, 8080)`
2. Now, create a xampp.ini file where the xampp-control.exe located and put the code into it:

   `[PORTS]`

   `apache = 8080`
3. Now restart the xampp.

Hope, it will work to change the apache port. But if you have installed oracle 10g client or any software in which perl is installed then do some more steps like bellow:

4.change the lines from:

```
`# Perl settings`

`Include "conf/extra/httpd-perl.conf"`
```

to

```
 `# Perl settings`

 `#Include "conf/extra/httpd-perl.conf"`
```

Now restart the xampp and it works properly in 8080 port.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem in TeamViewer application - it uses port 80 by default. Under advanced setting I made changes so the application will not use port 80 or 443 for incoming connections. Then switched of xammp and ran again. It works!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and after a bit of research, found out that the culprit in my case was the **"World Wide Web Publishing Service"** (**W3SVC** in the **iissvcs** Group).

Apache in XAMPP ran without a problem after *stopping this service* in my case.

Answer (score 0):

My XAMPP Apache all of the sudden wouldn't start, and, while I wasn't getting that error message specifically, it was because I installed a Skype upgrade, and Skype took over port 80 when my PC started which blocked Apache.  I tweaked a Skype advanced setting to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue hasnt been solved, scan this page for the "windows auto fix" link. It worked for me: Ran the tool, restarted PC, all ports open, instantly on.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811259/en

GL

Answer (score 0):

This might help others that's why I am posting my particular solution. I recently swapped Zend Server CE for XAMPP (2.5). The VHOSTS file had to be set-up with an Include directive to an error_log. I was having issues with SVN so I wiped the project I am working on to get a fresh install. However, I happened to start XAMPP prior to doing an svn checkout. That's when I noticed apache doing the Busy...Apache started [Port 80] business. Someone's comment on this thread reminded me of the Include directive. I climbed through the directories and added a blank error_log and blammo! Apache started up nicely.

This might help someone else too :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved it by opening xampp\apache\conf\http.conf.

I changed Listen 80 to Listen 2337
Above that line I had to add Listen 127.0.0.1:80

Then I opened xampp\apache\conf\httpd-ssl.conf

I changed Listen 80 to Listen 7332

Then I could connect to localhost again.